# iOS 6 - Mapview, overlay fades in

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6, overlay

I have been building an app which draw the lines of the current user moving along the map. Now, in iOS5 when I add the overlay to the mapview, it justs add it directly, in iOS6 it adds the overlay with "fade in" animation. I don't want this annoying animation. I also have a function which plays the trail upon the coordinates saved (after the user is done running or walking), when I play this, the lines flicker very fast, just because of this animation. This is really annoying and I really would appreciate any guidance or a solution to get rid of this animation.

Code for adding overlays:

```
MKMapPoint *pointsArray = malloc(sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D)*2);
pointsArray[0]= MKMapPointForCoordinate(oldLocation.coordinate); 
pointsArray[1]= MKMapPointForCoordinate(newLocation.coordinate);
self.routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithPoints:pointsArray count:2];
free(pointsArray);    
[self.mapView addOverlay:self.routeLine];
```

Code for displaying overlay:

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay{
    MKOverlayView *overlayView = nil;
    MKPolylineView  *routeLineView = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:(MKPolyline *)overlay];
    routeLineView.fillColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    routeLineView.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    routeLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    routeLineView.lineWidth = 10;
    routeLineView.lineCap = kCGLineCapRound;
    overlayView = routeLineView;
    return overlayView;
}
```

Thanks!

EDIT:

Code for going through the path:

```
playTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:interval
                                                 target:self
                                               selector:@selector(playPathTimer)
                                               userInfo:nil
                                                repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:playTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];

- (void)playPathTimer{
    MKMapPoint *pointsArray = malloc(sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D) * 2);
    double latitude1 = ((WorldPoint *)[coordsArray objectAtIndex:playCounter]).latitude.doubleValue;
    double longitude1 = ((WorldPoint *)[coordsArray objectAtIndex:playCounter]).longitude.doubleValue;
    double latitude2 = ((WorldPoint *)[coordsArray objectAtIndex:playCounter+nextCord]).latitude.doubleValue;
    double longitude2 = ((WorldPoint *)[coordsArray objectAtIndex:playCounter+nextCord]).longitude.doubleValue;
    CLLocation *location1 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude1, longitude1)
                                                          altitude:0
                                                horizontalAccuracy:0
                                                  verticalAccuracy:0
                                                         timestamp:[NSDate date]];
    CLLocation *location2 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude2, longitude2)
                                                          altitude:0
                                                horizontalAccuracy:0
                                                  verticalAccuracy:0
                                                         timestamp:[NSDate date]];
    pointsArray[0] = MKMapPointForCoordinate(location1.coordinate);
    pointsArray[1] = MKMapPointForCoordinate(location2.coordinate);
    self.routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithPoints:pointsArray count:2];
    free(pointsArray);

    [self.mapView addOverlay:self.routeLine];
    [playRouteLines addObject:self.routeLine];


//    self.mapView.centerCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude1, longitude1);

    playCounter = playCounter + nextCord;
    if(playCounter + nextCord >= coordsArray.count){
//        [displayLink setPaused:YES];
//        [displayLink invalidate];
       [playTimer invalidate];
        playTimer = nil;
        playCounter = 0;
        [self showStartAndEndFlags];
        if(ee.trail.checkpoint.count > 0){
            [self showCheckpoints];
        }
        self.playButton.enabled = YES;
        MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [self.mapView regionThatFits:[self getRegionWithCorrectZooming]];
        [self.mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: Does that only happen in simulator or device? I have something like that and I see no major flickering.

Comment: It happens on the device only, not the simulator

Comment: I'll look into it but show also the code you use for going through the path. It may have something to do with that.

Comment: Added the code for going through the path, nothing out of the ordinary!

Comment: I'm still looking at the code but you don't need to add the timer to the run loop. The NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: already does that. This can be relevant if the timer fires twice. I'll comment further findings.

Comment: Yeah, that is true, I removed it so it doesn't add the timer again, but still the same issue though :/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23300/discussion-between-fabio-oliveira-and-carnal)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a MKPolylineView you can use your own subclass of MKOverlayView (superclass of MKPolylineView) and then override drawMapRect:zoomScale:inContext: where you draw the lines yourself.

I guess with this you won't have any fade in animation (I'm using it and never noticed any animation).

Try the following code for your drawMapRect:zoomScale:inContext: implementation.
You need to create the properties lineColor(CGColor) and lineWidth (CGFloat).

```
- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CGContextRef)context {
    MKPolyline *polyline = self.overlay;
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, self.lineColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, self.lineWidth/zoomScale);

    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPoint *points = malloc(sizeof(CGPoint)*polyline.pointCount);
    for (int i=0; i<polyline.pointCount; i++) {
        points[i] = [self pointForMapPoint:polyline.points[i]];
    }
    CGPathAddLines(path, NULL, points, polyline.pointCount);

    CGContextAddPath(context, path);

    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke);
    CGPathRelease(path);
    free(points);
}
```

Comment: Then I need to subclass MKMapView?

Comment: No. You need to subclass MKOverlayView and instead of using a MKPolylineView you use your new subclass. I'm going to rephrase to make the answer clearer.

Comment: could u give me an example over your overridden method?

Comment: Added sample code. Try it out and let me know how it works. I couldn't test it so let me know if you find something not working.

Comment: he problem still remains, it has nothing to do with adding the overlay. I even used Apples Breadcrumb to achieve the result, but it didn't work either. It's a bug in iOS 6 :S

Comment: Try not to start the animation at the same time you add the overlay. Add the overlay first and only then you start the animation to go from one point to another. If both animations don't occur at the same time maybe the lines don't flicker.

Comment: the animation is built in the method "addOverlay"

Comment: Yes but the flickering comes from animating the setRegion: at the same time. If they don't happen at the same time you won't have any flickering.

Comment: I don't use the method setRegion anywhere when playing the path :S

Comment: It's the last line on the `playPathTimer`method. At least in the pasted code.

Comment: I changed my code, but even though.. the last line of code as you mentioned, runs only when the whole path is done drawing! So it has nothing to do with that!